# Unable to compile-Getting Error Message

Tags: pdftex, pdf, texstudio

Can someone please help me with the following:

I have written the following code but not able to compile it.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
Hi

\end{document}
```

I have installed MikTeX, updated it and then installed TeXstudio, I dont know what I am doing wrong.

I am getting the following error message:

```
Sorry, but pdflatex.exe did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\pdflatex.log

Process exited with error(s)
```

When I opened the log file, I got the following written there. What can I do to fix it?

```
2020-08-27 20:43:19,953+0530 INFO  pdflatex - this process (3080) started by 'texstudio' with command line: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode aa.tex
2020-08-27 20:43:19,968+0530 INFO  pdflatex - allowing known shell commands
2020-08-27 20:43:19,968+0530 INFO  pdflatex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
2020-08-27 20:43:20,031+0530 INFO  pdflatex - going to create file: pdflatex.fmt
2020-08-27 20:43:20,109+0530 INFO  pdflatex.core - start process: initexmf --dump-by-name=pdflatex --engine=pdftex
2020-08-27 20:43:23,842+0530 ERROR pdflatex - C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\initexmf.exe did not succeed; exitCode: 1
2020-08-27 20:43:23,842+0530 ERROR pdflatex - output:
2020-08-27 20:43:23,842+0530 ERROR pdflatex - 
Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\initexmf.log

2020-08-27 20:43:23,842+0530 FATAL pdflatex.core - The memory dump file could not be found.
2020-08-27 20:43:23,842+0530 FATAL pdflatex.core - Data: fileName="pdflatex.fmt"
2020-08-27 20:43:23,842+0530 FATAL pdflatex.core - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\texmfapp.cpp:708
2020-08-27 20:43:23,842+0530 FATAL pdflatex - The memory dump file could not be found.
2020-08-27 20:43:23,842+0530 FATAL pdflatex - Info: fileName="pdflatex.fmt"
2020-08-27 20:43:23,842+0530 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\texmfapp.cpp
2020-08-27 20:43:23,842+0530 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 708
2020-08-27 20:43:23,842+0530 INFO  pdflatex - this process (3080) finishes with exit code 1
```

I dont know why I am unable to compile any document. Please help someone.

Comment: miktex could not create the format. Check if C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\initexmf.log says anything useful.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer; what is the way to fix it? I have provided all the relevant files

Comment: Run the line initexmf --dump-by-name=pdflatex --engine=pdftex in a command line. Perhaps you then get a better error message.